# Bypass few lines in Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, next.js

I need to integrate the SDK into my next.js project via cdn
So I need to put the `<script src='<url>' />` into my code.
then run `window.sdk = new PrivateSDK()` and
`window.sdk.someFunction()`

I can bypass the eslint unallowed reassign warning using `/* eslint-disable */`
But How can I bypass the flow checking ?

It returns `Cannot resolve name PrivateSDK.` in `window.sdk = new PrivateSDK()`
and

`Cannot resolve name sdk.` in `window.sdk.someFunction()`

Comment: hmm maybe try to wrap your new PrivateSDK() with try-catch block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of options. If you want to simply suppress the errors, you can define the [supress_comment option](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) in your .flowconfig:

```
suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe
```

And then you can leave a comment `// $FlowFixMe` on the line above where you want to suppress the error.

Alternatively, you could do something like this to get around the type checking on window by reassigning it to a variable with `any` type:

```
let windowAny: any = window;
windowAny.sdk = new windowAny.PrivateSDK();
windowAny.sdk.someFunction()
```